# C++ cant find cmd using FindWindow()

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND handle = FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass","C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe");
    if (handle == NULL)
        cout << "Window not found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Window found " << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

I tried using this code to find handle of the running cmd application , But FindWindow() is unable to find the handle.It shows Winodw not found.Pls help.

Comment: Would [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow) be a better choice?

Comment: GetConsoleWindow() would return the handle of the current cosole (cmd window) in which the programme is running. I actually want to find the handle of a different console(cnd window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unicode, try this snippet:

```
HWND handle = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");
```

Comment: Could u explain why u put "\\" instead of " \"..?

Comment: c++ parser and compiler understand that way. In VS template \\ doublebackslash produce a \ single backslash

Comment: @EzioBlaze backslashes start escape characters such as '\n' which is the end line character. the escape sequence for the char '\' is "\\" (single backslash). Without the second backslash, the compiler would think there is a '\w', a '\s', and a '\c' which is not what you would intend (a single backslash).